# R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

it's been a little while since I made an android project..
But recently I upgraded my eclipse version and a number of plugins etc..

Now all my projects won't compile and R cannot be resolved.  ugh..

Comment: Have you tried to 'Clean' the projects to force a rebuild?

Comment: Are you importing R from the android namespace instead of your own?

Comment: no import, already cleaned..  I can make a project and instantly their is a red X over the project name..

Comment: if there is no reference in the code to R.. it says "there are errors in the project, please fix before running your application".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a good answer. It's just what worked for me.

I just had the same problem a few days ago. Fixing R isn't the answer. I tried for a couple of hours. It won't work. Every id, every attr, every layout, every thing depends on R. Almost every statement in the code is red lined.

To fix it, I had to delete the workspace and start up a new one. Then restore everything from the last working backups. (If you don't already, Export the file structure about every couple of hours. Keep at least the last 3. It will save you someday.)

I think  the problem occurred when I was working with the emulator. I was exiting from a hung start. I was going to restart after deleting an emulator that was junked up and recreate it. I exited Eclipse before clicking the 'not responding/cancel' message for the emulator. I didn't see the saving the environment progress bar from Eclipse when I stopped it. I think the workspace metadata or similar was blasted.

Comment: In passing, one of the things I tried was an Import of the fully qualified R. It couldn't find R even though it was listed in the tree.

Comment: sounds like I'm not going to find an easy answer to this problem..  =/  I've heard some vicious stories about recent upgrades to the Eclipse IDE causing numerous issues.  I'm curious if that's where my problems started..

Comment: UPDATE - I can build a new workspace very quickly because I'm using Eclipse Indigo.  Built a new project, and everything was fine.. other than the fact that my 1yr keygen has expired which was easily fixed.  So R is recognized in my new workspace.. but not my old one =/

Comment: Glad it worked out. I also wonder about a built in error. First disaster level problem since January. I just upgraded myself. Oh well, I'm even backing up the workspace at the end of each day. I tested and you can delete a workspace and rename an old one...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here's the steps to solve:
if you have the error in only one activity then jump to step 5. if all the activities have the same error then go step 1.

1. click on project>>clear.
2. check the console for errors on the xml or resources files, as if error in the any will prevent the R.java from being generated
3. for me there was resources that was named with "-" and this caused an error.
4. After that clear the project again this should fix it.. if not
5. (this usually cause only on activity of generating this error)make sure your activity does not contain import of R.java
6. if the problem persists then you have to go for the long dummy way of debugging errors, by copying the project folder somewhere as a backup (This is very important), start deleting layouts one by one...
7. everytime you delete a layout make sure to delete all the resources from the project that is used by that layout and delete it's id from the manifest and delete the activity associated with it.. (start with the activity that's causing the error).
8. keep clearing the project after every delete to narrow down the cause of the problem.
9. grab a cup of coffee; this might take a while, you could also take another approach by creating a new project and import activities, layouts and resources one by one.
10. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Look for problems that are not 'R' - related and fix them (these problems will prevent the R file from being built). Then clean your projects to invoke the generation of the R file.

Comment: did and done.. I have 30+ projects all not picking up R.  There were no problems 2 weeks ago, so obviously no logic or syntax errors.  Cleaned everything..

Comment: all the simple things have been checked.. that stupid import statement isn't there.. hierarchy looks fine.  No apparent errors in the main.xml, R.java, or manifest.xml.  Maybe a classpath issue??